# Find unique and duplicate value

Tags: java, arrays, apache, apache-poi

In **cells1** I have list of value i.e. [4000,4001,4002,4003] and in **cells2** having i.e [1234,4000]. I am trying to find duplicates and unique value but even its having duplicate value its every time going to else part. why any code wrong .

```
Iterator itr = cells2.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext()){
      HSSFCell s = (HSSFCell) itr.next();
      boolean sta = cells1.contains(s.getStringCellValue());
        if(sta==true){
        System.out.println("Dublicate:>>>>"+s.toString());
         }else{
           System.out.println("unique value:>>>>:"+s.toString());
              }
         }
     }
```

**out put value is :**

unique value:>>>>:1234

unique value:>>>>:4000 **<- which is wrong out put**

Comment: FYI you can just do `if(sta)`.

Comment: What does `getStringCellValue()` return. Why not do `toString()` here?

Comment: @Stanley  List<Cell> cells1 = new ArrayList<Cell>();

Comment: @AniketThakur I use toSring() even but no changes same out put.

Comment: `List<Cell> cells2 = new ArrayList<Cell>();` Considering this your code will not work unless you have overiden `.equals()` in your `Cell` class. Also then no need to use `getStringCellValue()` or `toString()`.

Comment: Thanks to all , for your valuable info.

Answer (score 1):

From Your comment `cells1` is `ArrayList<Cell>` so you are calling `cells1.contains(s.getStringCellValue());` means finding `String` in `ArrayList` of `Cells` which will not do anything that's why it's going in to the else part.

Ultimately you are trying to find `String` in `Cells` which is not possible directly.

You have to compare `String` value of each cell (means cell's `String` value) of `ArrayList<Cell>` with your `s.getStringCellValue()` you have to override `contains` method or declare your own method.

```
public boolean isThereAnyCellWithString(String str){
//Iterate over cells1 and compare 
//Use contains here if you want to or equals to find exact match
 for(HSSFCell cell : cells1){
     if(cell.getStringCellValue().contains(str))
     return true;
 }
 return false;
}
```